# Validating Base64 Encoded String

Tags: java, string, base64, encode

For the following code when i try to base64 encode a string.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Codec {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String clrTxt = "Hello world";
      String encodedTxt;

      encodedText = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(clearText.getBytes()));
      System.out.println("Encoded: " + encodedText);
      System.out.println("Decoded:" 
          + new String(Base64.decodeBase64(encodedText.getBytes())));
      //    
      // output :
      //   Encoded: **SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=**
      //   Decoded:Hello world      
  }
}
```

In the encoded String when i try to insert some extraa characters, say --> "SGVsb***G8ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF1234234***gd29ybGQ="
-> i get a clear text with some diacritical characters in it. Is there a method to validate and overcome this. Please reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you adding extra characters in a Base64-encoded string in the first place?

Comment: as a measure of security. "Hello world is just an example". what if in case of parsing a string which is sensitive that will be used as parameters? And so it does decodes the string but with improper response. Why shudnt i rather validate and then parse if the encoded string is completely valid and match the pattern while decoding?

Comment: Base64 is just a way to encode arbitrary bytes into a textual format. It doesn't have anything to do with security. If you want to make sure some text received from a third party hasn't been modified by a man-in-the-middle, use cryptographic signatures.

Answer (score 3):

You have very limited ability to validate a base-64 string all by itself: as long as the encoded string has the correct length (i.e. the length, including the trailing equal signs, is divisible by four) and the string consists of only proper base64 characters, it is deemed a valid string.

If you need to tamper-proof your message, you need to prepare an additional piece of data describing the original text, and pass it to the destination along with your base64 encoded data. In the simplest case, it could be a checksum of the text, but that scheme is easy to beat. A better approach is to prepare a *digest* of the original text using a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), and pass that digest along with the base64 encoded text to the destination.

Keep in mind that passing a digest will not prevent [man-in-the-middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack#Defenses_against_the_attack), because the attacker can send his own digest along with a tampered message.

Comment: A digest that includes a secret, such as `sha1(plaintext + password)` can be used to detect tampering by MITM.